# jQuery UI Droppable Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Over on http://lab.2toria.com/reflex/index2.php I've started working on an idea for a game I'm building.

If you click and drag the block on the right to the main grid, you'll see that, as you drag over it, the blocks highlight.  If you drop, the blocks get a dark gray border.  This is great, but if you then drag a block over a cell/block that is already dark gray, it resets to default of light gray as you pass over it.

What do I need to do to stop this happening?  I want the blocks that are dark gray to remain that color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hoverClass` is `path` in the droppable that is also what you are setting as the class once you drop. When you enter that droppable with a draggable and exit it removes your class. Why not create two seperate classes with the same styling rules and use one as the `hoverClass` and the other as the dropped class.

```
$(".grid").droppable({
    hoverClass: "hovered",
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).addClass("path");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `hover` class, because is the same as your `drop` class. When `mouseover` on the element add the class and when on `mouseout` remove it. Use diferent class, that should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$(".grid").click(function() {
    //     $(this).addClass("path");
    //})
    $("#pathpiece").draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 1,
        helper: "clone"
    });

    $(".grid").droppable({
        // Create a hoverPath class
        hoverClass: "hoverPath",
        drop: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).addClass("path");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit redundant, but you could make a separate class for the hover class and the class that gets applied when you drop the block.

So you would have

```
.path {
    border: 2px solid Gray;
}
.dropped {
    border: 2px solid Gray;
}
```

And then your droppable function would be

```
$(".grid").droppable({
    hoverClass: "path",
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).addClass("dropped");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aymhZ/